# How to host a bot in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: python, azure

Disclaimer: NOT a Microsoft Bot Framework bot.

I want to host Python bot in Microsoft Azure. It works like so:

```py
while True:
    handle_events(poll_server())
```

So I basically want to run Python script to work forever.

I've started with Python webapp sample (created via `az webapp up`). It runs gunicorn and searches for Flask or something, which is not my case. I've configured startup command as `python .../main.py`, and it kinda works, but it is restarted every 5 minutes (I guess, because my app does not respond to HTTP requests).

I think there should be some other type of Azure resource/container, which allows running own services, but I can't find any. Is there something similar to `az webapp up` or I should create an empty VM/container and manually deploy app there?

Comment: I would just package your python app into a container. Then you can use Azure WebApp for Containers or also AKS or ACI to host it.

Comment: @silent do you mean some docker yaml stuff? I never really tried that, so I'm not completely sure how it's done. The way I see it I should write some yaml and insert it somewhere in Azure. Am I correct?

Comment: No, I mean to build a docker image for your app. https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application

Comment: And once you have that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker-go#create-a-web-app

Comment: @silent I guess that answers my question (though it looks like you can't specify private Docker Hub image as there is no way to specify login/password -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/container?view=azure-cli-latest -- while there is for vcs -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest ).

Comment: yes you can also use a private registry. Don't know the exact CLI parameters but it's doable through the Portal so there must be a way in the CLI as well :)

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, because the app is not responding to web requests, the app is spinning down regularly and having to restart. This is the default behavior for Azure App Services, but there are a couple ways to keep an App Service up and running.

1. If you are on a Standard App Service Plan or higher, go into the app settings and enable "Always On". This will prevent the app from spinning down by sending a request at regular intervals. This is the preferred method of doing this.
2. Implement the Always On feature yourself by having some process (there are a lot of options for implementing this) ping the App Service with an HTTP request every few minutes.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, 1 is how it is right now. But the question is what should I do if my script is not a web server (that is, does not respond to periodic requests)? @silent over there adviced making a container, which, I think, is the right way to do that for non-server apps. As a temporary workaround I'm running my app in a thread along with Flask server though, so I kinda use what you've described as 1.

Comment: Since the key is having the App Service respond to an occasional request, putting the app in a container doesn't really help on that front, though an Azure Container Instance is viable.The solution you are using is essentially the correct one. If you want to improve it a bit, you can deploy your python script as a WebJob, leaving the app open to respond to requests. That way you won't have to mix a Flask server in with your bot.